Yoneda embedding for the $\omega$ category
Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" suggests the following exercise (2.2.iii) on the Yoneda lemma:

As discussed [...], diagrams of shape $\omega$ are determined by a countably infinite family of objects and a countable infinite sequence of morphisms.
Describe the Yoneda embedding $y : \omega \rightarrow Set^{\omega^{op}}$ in this manner (as a family of $\omega^{op}$-indexed functors and natural transformations). Prove directly, without appealing to the Yoneda lemma, that y is full and faithful.

I'm not quite sure what exactly is meant by "in this manner" here. Sure, I (hopefully) understand the image of the embedding in question: an $n : \omega$ is mapped to the (contravariant) functor $\omega(—, n)$ (which, if we think of $\omega$ as the ordered set of natural numbers, can be understood as providing a witness of $m \leq n$ for corresponding $m$, or an empty set otherwise), and an $\omega$-arrow $m \rightarrow n$ (which is a witness of $m \leq n$) is mapped to the obvious natural transformation $\omega(—, m) \Rightarrow \omega(—, n)$, which itself can be seen as expressing the transitivity of the relation in question ("give me proof of $a \leq m$, and I give you proof of $a \leq n$").
Is that what's implied here, or did Riehl mean something else entirely?

Yes. And fullness of the functor (it is faithful anyway) means that if two natural numbers $n,m$ satisfy
$\forall a : a \leq n \implies a \leq m,$
then we have $n \leq m$. This is actually useful to know. You can either deduce this fact from the Yoneda Lemma, or prove it directly (set $a = n$ etc.) - which is of course just the general Yoneda proof presented in a special case.
The same works for every poset.
